# How to add border to carousel with two items

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

My code is as below

http://jsfiddle.net/gXN2u/219/

I am trying to add a border to each of the items with the class `item-list`. However it doesn't show.

My actual slider is a vertical slider.

What i want to achieve:

![enter image description here][1]

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just clear the float

```
 <div class="item-list clearfix">
```

add clear fix style in your style sheet

or add float and width for the `.item-list`

```
.item-list {
   border: 8px solid red;
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 10px #888888;
   border-radius: 7px;
   -moz-border-radius: 7px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
   float: left;/*added*/
   width: 100%;/*added*/
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Or, you can use `overflow` property

```
.item-list {
    border-top: 1px solid red;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.item-list:first-child {
    border-top: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ewygux9t/